# Moving from Azure S3 to P2V2 - IP question

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans, azure-vm-scale-set

We have a client that’s moving from Azure S3 to P2V2 for their CD environment to work on performance improvements. When I click P2V2 in the Scale Up area, I get a warning that outbound IP addresses may change, with a link to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#when-outbound-ips-change

What we’re trying to nail down is that the site IP that the domain resolves to will NOT change during this; it’s listed as one of the outbound IPs as well, but we mainly want to be sure that we don’t have to change the DNS again during this process. One of our other clients did a similar thing and did not have a change to the inbound IP, but I would like to get either more anecdotal evidence or documentation that we don’t have to worry about that. (We’re still going to have the client IT on standby for DNS changes if it comes to it.)

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. the document you provided is the right one that describes when the inbound and outbound IP of the Web App would change. I understand you want to get more evidence, so here are more details about the [inbound](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/ip-address-change-inbound) and [outbound](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/ip-address-change-outbound) IP of the Web App.

Comment: It looks like the inbound IP is fine, we did some experiments and talked to Microsoft.